# Currency converter in html+php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm writing now very simple currency converter with fixed values of convertions. I'm trying to make it work within a single file containing php script for calculations and a form sending data via post. My code at now looks like this:

```
<?php
$eurToUsd=1.11;
$usdToEur = 0.94;
$eurToPln = 4.39;
$plnToEur = 0.28;
$usdToPln = 3.87;
$plnToUsd = 0.23;

if (isset($_POST['conversionType'])) {

$eurToUsdVal=$_POST['EURtoUSD'];
$usdToEurVal=$_POST['USDtoEUR'];
$eurToPlnVal=$_POST['EURtoPLN'];
$plnToEurVal=$_POST['PLNtoEUR'];
$usdToPLNVal=$_POST['USDtoPLN'];
$plnToUsdVal=$_POST['PLNtoUSD'];
    if ($_POST['EURtoUSD']) {
        echo $eurToUsdVal*$eurToUsd;
    } elseif ($_POST['USDtoEUR']) {
        echo $usdToEurVal*$usdToEur;
    } elseif ($_POST['EURtoPLN']) {
        echo $eurToPlnVal*$eurToPln;
    } elseif ($_POST['PLNtoEUR']) {
        echo $plnToEurVal*$plnToEur;
    } elseif ($_POST['USDtoPLN']) {
        echo $usdToPlnVal*$usdToPln;
    } elseif ($_POST['PLNtousUSD']) {
        echo $plnToUsdVal*$plnToUsd;
    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <label>
        Amount:
        <input type="number" min="0.00" step="0.01" name="cashAmount">
    </label>
    <label>
        Conversion:
        <input type="radio" name="conversionType" value="EURtoUSD" checked> EUR → USD <br>
        <input type="radio" name="conversionType" value="USDtoEUR" > USD → EUR <br>
        <input type="radio" name="conversionType" value="EURtoPLN" > EUR → PLN <br>
        <input type="radio" name="conversionType" value="PLNtoEUR" > PLN → USD <br>
        <input type="radio" name="conversionType" value="USDtoPLN" > USD → PLN <br>
        <input type="radio" name="conversionType" value="PLNtoUSD" > PLN → USD <br>
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

when i'm trying to use this converter i am getting error telling "Undefined index: EURtoUSD" and the same for other conversions. To be precise i'm getting list of errors like this for all convertions in this php file. What do i miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's pretty sure you will have an error "Undefined index: EURtoUSD", because the name of your input text is conversionType.

so what you have to do is remove this

```
$eurToUsdVal=$_POST['EURtoUSD'];
$usdToEurVal=$_POST['USDtoEUR'];
$eurToPlnVal=$_POST['EURtoPLN'];
$plnToEurVal=$_POST['PLNtoEUR'];
$usdToPLNVal=$_POST['USDtoPLN'];
$plnToUsdVal=$_POST['PLNtoUSD'];
```

and change the condition like this

```
if ($_POST['conversionType'] == "EURtoUSD") {
    echo $eurToUsd*$_POST['conversionType'];
// and so on
```

Comment: Thx, i edited my code following your suggestion but now every time as output i get 0, no matter what i input.

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST['conversionType'])` and let us know the result

Comment: For test i did input 22 and vardump outputted this: string 'EURtoUSD' (length=8)

Comment: Anyone have any ideas how to solve this issue and properly send input via post method in this case? Seems like value is being send and received instead of input.

Comment: it should be `$_POST['cashAmount'] * $eurToUsd`

Comment: Yes Zaid, you are right. That's where i had mistake in my code, i was picking wrong variable to my calculation and i was picking meaningless string instead of proper value.